# Rename multiple files with zmv but not directories

Tags: linux, debian, rename, zsh

I would like to rename multiple files (add an extension).. i can use zmv of zsh with

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(**/)(*)' '$1$2.myextension'
```

but this will rename also all the dirs that are inside the current dir... what can i do to rename only files (recursively) and avoid dirs renaming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://strcat.de/zsh/#zmv):

```
# Rename names of all files under the current Dir to lower case, but keep Dir names as-is. 
  $ zmv -Qv '(**/)(*)(.D)' '$1${(L)2}'
```

so I think the `(.D)` is what you require. The 'period' indicates matching on regular files (not directories) and the `D` enables the `GLOB_DOTS` option.

Comment: Thanks so much, however it's also necessary the -Q :)

Comment: "Force bare glob qualifiers on. Don’t turn this on unless you are actually using glob qualifiers in a pattern."

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv